# Why to use intersection with empty object type and mapped type in TypeScipt

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

In the source code of [ts-toolbelt](https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt), there is often an intersection of an empty object and a mapped type. For what purpose is this done?

```
export type ReadonlyFlat<O> = {
  +readonly [K in keyof O]: O[K];
} & {}; // there

export type OptionalFlat<O> = {
  [K in keyof O]?: O[K];
} & {}; // there

type __Pick<O extends object, K extends keyof O> = {
  [P in K]: O[P];
} & {}; // there
```

Comment: https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt/commit/1b1ac71c337619b5a7e75cf8dca2612fdc0e41ff is the commit that did this, whose message is "fix(deep): over-computation on deep types & recursive mapped types".  Not sure if there's any more information about that.

Comment: Also from that commit: "_add `& {}` for better computation we can only do this if the mapped type is not intended to go deep (recurse) because `& {}` forces computation, if we do it deeply => resolves to `any` this happens only when a type is nested within itself => infinite recursion_"

Comment: Note that I'm not really sure how to turn this into an answer; it's specific to a particular library and without some [mre] of the problem it claims to prevent it's hard to know what to say that isn't just opinion or conjecture.